# Replace text on page depending on page URL

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

We are already replacing text with images on the website but have run into a little problem due to the platform we're running on - which is proprietary and provides limited access.

Our goal is to replace the price with an image, ONLY for this specific brand and all items within it.

It seems that forming some sort of expression to look at the current URL and then if it fits to replace the text with the image.

Is this valid thinking and if so how do I go about doing this?

[Here is a link to a sample product](http://thmotorsports.com/kw_suspension/kw_variant_3_coilovers/35220011/i-68657.aspx) that is within the brand 'KW Suspension';

Comment: I would be careful replacing HTML like this on the client side for SEO. You don't want to be dinged for cloaking

Comment: Thank you Amin, this is actually something we must do to hide the price and have the customer add to cart prior to seeing the cost of an item.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your time, patience, and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that shouldn't be too hard,

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ( /.*\/kw_suspension\/.*/i.test(location.href) ) {
              $(".yourprice").html("<img src='myimg.png' />");
        }
    });

</script>
```

you could also change it to check using a regexp, you just change what is within the () to fit your criteria.

**EDIT**

Added surrounding code and changed to regexp as suggested by OP.

Comment: Thank you but this looks as if would handle only one url at a time would it not? Can I make it so it will cover any url with /kw_suspension/ in it to cover all sub-categories & products?

Comment: yes, you just replace the condition to use a regexp. if ( /.*\/kw_suspension\/.*/i.test(location.href) ) {...

Comment: Which is exactly what jake's answer does.

Comment: this seems to be a valid solution, however I cannot get it to work, can you please include the full script including the open and close script tags so I can better try it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Tentonaxe, we've run into an issue with obfuscated urls based on referrer. Instead of looking at the URL how would I modify it to look at the H1 tag to see if it contains the brand in question?

Here is the sample URL: http://bit.ly/pUrdj2

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the location.href which would return a string for the current windows url and you could use a regex match to see if the brand is in the ur.  You can then do a replace to replace the pricing span:

```
var matcher = new Regexp(/kw_suspension/);
if(x.test(location.href){
  $('#ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_YourPriceLabel').replace(better html here);
}
```

The above will just simply see if kw_suspension is in the url and then it replaces the span with the price with something else.

Comment: Hi Jake, I tried testing this and I'm probably doing something wrong. Here is your code replaced to another brand and tested on another website.

Website: http://bit.ly/oNOA4a

Comment: For that url you would replace kw_suspesion with injen

Comment: I tried replacing that and if you look at the code I also tried this as well as others with no results. If you can provide the full code I believe that may be my issue - some small issue when trying to add this. `<script type="text/javascript">
var matcher = new Regexp(/injen/);
if(x.test(location.href){
  $('#ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_YourPriceLabel').replace("<img border='0' style='text-align:center;margin:5px 0;' src='/storage/thawte.jpg' />");
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to see if the url contains your keyword.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urlString =  location.href; //get URL string

    if( urlString.string.indexOf("kw_suspension") != -1){
       $('div.yourprice').empty().html('<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to this post. 

Would I just add;

`$(".yourprice").html("<img src='/storage/thawte.jpg'/>");`

 where you have //replace your image? If you can provide me with the full code including <script></script> tags? I would greatly appreciate it since I believe I'm formatting this wrong.